# Parsing error with in ArcPy code

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, if-statement

I have the following code in Python for a tool I want to build. For some reason I viewshed don't exist in the folder I have chose (out). Also when I am trying to define the output workspace every time the file I have created inside the Input folder is deleted so I created one more outside of the folder where my input data are. Why is that? I am using ArcGis 10.2.2

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pnt*", "Point")
ras = arcpy.ListRasters("clip*", "GRID")
point = "Pntclip_pol1"
dem = "clip_pol1"
i = 1
for shp in fc:
    for raster in ras:
        if (shp == 'point' and raster == 'dem'):
            inRaster = raster
            inObserverFeatures = shp
            outViewshed = Viewshed(inRaster, inObserverFeatures, "")
            outViewshed.save(out + "view" + str(i))
            i = int(i) + 1
            point = "Pntclip_pol" + str(i)
            dem = "clippol" + str(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry too much about setting the `env.workspace`. Just build the full path yourself with the `os` module:

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
out = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Pnt*", "Point")
ras = arcpy.ListRasters("clip*", "GRID")
point = "Pntclip_pol{}"
dem = "clip_pol{}"
i = 1
for shp in fc:
    for raster in ras:
        if (shp == point.format(i) and raster == point.format(i)):
            path = os.path.join(workspace, '{}_view_{}'.format(out, i))
            outViewshed = arcpy.sa.Viewshed(raster, shp, "")
            outViewshed.save(path)
            i += 1
```

Comment: The lines you threw are crucial for the tool, because I want to do some viewsheds for certain pairs of shp and dem. In any case it doesn't work either. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @por.bet It's not clear from the example code how `dem` and `point` are used. Unless your conditional statement was meant to compare the variables and not the strings. (i.e., `shp == point` not `shp == 'point'`. See the difference?

Comment: I have some points in the form of Pntclip_pol1, Pntclip_pol2 and some rasters in the form of clip_pol1, clip_pol2 etc. The statement is to make some viewsheds only for these pairs that end at 1,2,3,4..

Comment: @por.bet I understand that, but evaluating `shp == 'point'` will *always* be `False`. You need `shp == point`. See my edits

Comment: ok, i tried it , but nothing changed. I don't have error but I don' t get a result

Comment: @por.bet Then try things like printing out the `path` variable inside the loop. Do some troubleshooting here. I don't have your data to test on.

Comment: you've got curly brackets instead of () in the if line, that may be causing a problem.

Comment: @mr.adam instead of what? I don't get it. What have I different?

Comment: sorry, I meant in the code that @PaulH wrote, it should be `point.format(i)` instead of `point.format{i}`.

Comment: @mr.adam good catch, fixed

Comment: @por.bet I reset the `arcpy.env` in light of the fact it's not clear you weren't getting any output at all (it originally seemed as if it was being saved in the wrong directory)